# Missing assembly reference from a ASP.Net 5 application

Tags: asp.net-core

I am working on a team. The three other people on my team pulled down the new asp.net 5 application with no problems. I attempted to pull the application down from TFS and None of my DNX references are resolving. The errors I am getting is that I am missing namespaces / assembly references for the common libraries:

System,
Microsoft,
ASP.Net etc

None of my references are resolving.

As stated the three other people who pulled the project from TFS are not having any issues.

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: Did you run the command that pulls down the appropriate packages from NuGet? `dnu restore` if I remember right? Sounds like you need to talk to your team and find out what they did that you didn't do.

Comment: @mason We are using gulp for everything. Unfortunately I did exactly what they did. My machine just can't seem to pull in the appropriate assemblies.

Comment: Run `dnu restore`. See if that fixes the problem. If it doesn't, see if there are any error messages from dnu. Basically, troubleshoot it normally.

Comment: @DanielMann Where do you run that manually?

Comment: Command line, from the root of the application (where the `project.json` file lives)

Comment: @danielMann dnu is not recognized as a command

Comment: Ta-da! You have identified the problem.

Comment: You should now make sure you've [installed DNVM](https://github.com/aspnet/Home) properly and use [DNVM](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Version-Manager) to select which version  of DNX to use, which will add DNU to your PATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you install the .NET Version Manager (DNVM). You can do this by installing the [ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015 (Beta7)](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=623894) for Visual Studio 2015.

**Or:** install it manually using the instructions from [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Home#cmd). After that, run `dnvm upgrade` to download the latest stable DNX bits and you will be able to run `dnu restore` and so will Visual Studio.